# Wordpress menu right woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I do not quite know what to call it, but is a menu on the right side as I have highlighted in the image below, and remove this. How to do it?

[image: Photo]

Answer (score 0):

Go to widgets and delete the widgets you don't want there and also make the page full width so that no menu appears. Also can you tell me which theme you are using so I can better assist you.

Comment: The theme name is : Abaris

Comment: Thanks for replying. So I have gone through your theme settings and other things.

Comment: What you can do is go to the page you want full width and in template option select full width. You can see a demo here http://stackoverflow.cloudaccess.host/?page_id=2  The theme is same here also. If you want more help or want me to do this go to fiverr.com/hpareek07

Comment: But it is not possible has a possibility to take full size on the product page, it is what is the problem

Comment: what you have in the bottom where it is I want away